# If Statement when looping data from db in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I want to check my task id when looping for creating table . Is it possible to do that ???

```
             <table class="data-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>No.</th>
                        <th>ID Admin</th>
                        <th>IP Address</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th>Admin Activity</th>
                        <th>ID Stuff</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php 
                    foreach($all_data->result() as $data){
                    echo '
                        <tr>
                            <td>'.$data->id_history.'</td>
                            <td>'.$data->id_admin.'</td>
                            <td>'.$data->ipc.'</td>
                            <td>'.$data->task_date.'</td>
                            <td>'.$data->task_time.'</td>
                            'if ($data->id_task == 1){'  <========
                                <td>Login Site</td>      <========
                            '}else{'                     <========
                                <td>Logout Site</td>     <========
                            '}'                          <========
                            <td>-</td>
                        </tr>
                        ';
                        }
                    ?>          
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

That's a code for looping data in view.

```
function get_log_history(){
        $this -> db -> select('id_history, id_admin, ipc, task_date, task_time, id_task, id_stuff');
        $this -> db -> from('tbl_history');
        $this -> db -> where('id_task', 1);
        $this -> db -> or_where('id_task', 2);

        return $query = $this -> db -> get();
    }
```

That's a code for model. id task (foreign key) from tbl_task.

[image: Table relationship]

Comment: You will need to provide more info. Be clear about what is currently happening, why its wrong and what you would like to happen. Short answer though is yes, anything is possible

Comment: i got error like this : syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ',' or ';' .

Comment: The error message is crucial to debugging you should always include in your question. I got it though I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I spotted it. You can't put an if within an echo like that..

This is how it should look:

```
<?php foreach($all_data->result() as $data){ ?>
      <tr> 
           <td><?php echo $data->id_history;?></td> //no short tags
           <td><?=$data->id_admin;?></td> //using short tags
           //your other echos
    <?php if ($data->id_task == 1){ ?>
           <td>Login Site</td>  
    <?php }else{ ?>
           <td>Logout Site</td>
    <?php } ?>
       </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Or with a ternary operator it would look like this..

```
<?php foreach($all_data->result() as $data){ ?>
      <tr> 
           <td><?php echo $data->id_history;?></td> //no short tags
           <td><?=$data->id_admin;?></td> //using short tags
           //your other echos
           <td><?=$data->id_task===1?"Login Site":"Logout Site";?></td>
      </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: it's working for statement value .. but with the rest of data it just appear like value inside tag td .. ???

Comment: See updated answer I had a typo. All php variables need to be wrapped in php tags as above

Comment: Not a problem its easy when you know how. I updated my answer to use a ternery operator as its a bit neater although doesn't make any practical difference